# composer installation openssl missing on WindowsServer2008R2

Tags: php, composer-php, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to install *composer* on WindowsServer2008R2 but says that openssl extension is missing.

I modified the *php.ini* file so:

```
[ExtensionList]
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

I tried to search before posting but did not find anything about Win Server